What prevent Windows Vista event log viewer from showung events?
I developed manifest file for windows event log logging, and it is standart list of categories and events. It working great on Win 7+, but on Vista it shows strange window

I tried to find some information about this error, or some incompatible flags in xml schema, but nothing. How I can find the source of the problem?

....why (and how?) are you running Windows Vista in 2024?!

Anyway, the error message is (usually) because your Event Source is not properly registered - if you say it worked in Win7 but not Vista then I'll bet it's because the MC compiler you're using doesn't support Vista anymore? You really need to share more technical details - like exactly what MC compiler you're using, etc.

@Dai I'll check, all the problem is - I don't know where start reseach. Your idea about MC is interesting, I try it.

@Dai, you give me correct idea, old mc generate older bin and it works!

I used MC.exe from Windows 10 SDK, and  binary file have version 5. That is unsupported on Vista/XP. MC.exe from SDK7.1 generates version 3, that works.
